# Function reverts every time I call it

Tags: solidity, remix, payable

I am trying to write a Prediction Markets smart contract in Solidity.  Whenever I call the following function in Remix, the function is reverted, even though all the parameters and require statements are all fulfilled.  I also compiled the contract and no errors appeared.

> The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.

```
function buySharesYes(string memory _eventName, uint _payment) payable public {
        Event storage currentEvent = events[_eventName];
        require(_payment >= currentEvent.sharePriceYes, "Insufficient payment");
        uint shares = _payment / currentEvent.sharePriceYes;
        require(shares <= currentEvent.totalShares - currentEvent.sharesYes, "No more shares available");
        currentEvent.sharesYes += shares;
        balance += _payment;
        currentEvent.shareholdersYes.push(msg.sender);
        events[_eventName] = currentEvent;
        emit Purchase(msg.sender, _eventName, shares, _payment);
}
```

Here is the rest of my contract :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";

contract PredictionMarket {
    using SafeMath for uint;

    // The address of the contract owner
    address public owner;

    // A mapping of event names to event data
    mapping(string => Event) public events;

    // The event data for a specific event
    struct Event {
        address eventCreator;
        string name;
        uint eventId;
        uint totalShares;
        uint sharePriceYes;
        uint sharePriceNo;
        uint sharesYes;
        uint sharesNo;
        address[] shareholdersYes;
        address[] shareholdersNo;
    }

    uint public eventId = 0;

    // The balance of the contract
    uint public balance;

    // Events for logging
    event Purchase(address buyer, string eventName, uint shares, uint totalCost);
    event Refund(address buyer, string eventName, uint shares, uint refundAmount);
    event NewEvent(address eventCreator, string eventName, uint totalShares, uint sharePriceYes, uint sharePriceNo);

    // Constructor function
    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    // Function to create a new event
    function createEvent(string memory _eventName, uint _totalShares, uint _sharePriceYes, uint _sharePriceNo) public {
        require(_sharePriceYes > 0, "Share price must be greater than zero");
        require(_sharePriceNo > 0, "Share price must be greater than zero");
        eventId++; 
        events[_eventName] = Event(msg.sender, _eventName, eventId, _totalShares, 0, 0, _sharePriceYes, _sharePriceNo, new address[](0), new address[](0));
        emit NewEvent(msg.sender, _eventName, _totalShares, _sharePriceYes, _sharePriceNo);
    }

    // Function to buy shares in the "yes" outcome of a specific event
    function buySharesYes(string memory _eventName, uint _payment) payable public {
        Event storage currentEvent = events[_eventName];
        require(_payment >= currentEvent.sharePriceYes, "Insufficient payment");
        uint shares = _payment / currentEvent.sharePriceYes;
        require(shares <= currentEvent.totalShares - currentEvent.sharesYes, "No more shares available");
        currentEvent.sharesYes += shares;
        balance += _payment;
        currentEvent.shareholdersYes.push(msg.sender);
        events[_eventName] = currentEvent;
        emit Purchase(msg.sender, _eventName, shares, _payment);
    }


    // Function to buy shares in the "no" outcome of a specific event
    function buySharesNo(string memory _eventName, uint _payment) payable public {
        Event storage currentEvent = events[_eventName];
        require(_payment >= currentEvent.sharePriceNo, "Insufficient payment");
        uint shares = _payment / currentEvent.sharePriceNo;
        require(shares <= currentEvent.totalShares - currentEvent.sharesNo, "No more shares available");
        currentEvent.sharesNo += shares;
        balance += _payment;
        currentEvent.shareholdersNo.push(msg.sender);
        events[_eventName] = currentEvent;
        emit Purchase(msg.sender, _eventName, shares, _payment);
    }


    // Function to refund the purchase of shares
    function refund(string memory _eventName, uint shares) payable public {
        Event storage currentEvent = events[_eventName];
        require(shares <= currentEvent.sharesYes, "Insufficient shares owned");
        uint refundAmount = shares * currentEvent.sharePriceYes;
        balance -= refundAmount;
        currentEvent.sharesYes -= shares;
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(refundAmount);
        emit Refund(msg.sender, _eventName, shares, refundAmount);
    }

    // Function to close the market for a specific event and pay out profits to shareholders
    function closeMarket(string memory _eventName, bool result) payable public {
        Event storage currentEvent = events[_eventName];
        require(currentEvent.eventCreator == msg.sender, "Only the event creator can close this market");
        if (result) {
            // Calculate total profit for the "yes" outcome
            uint totalSharesYes = currentEvent.sharesYes;
            uint totalPayoutYes = totalSharesYes.mul(currentEvent.sharePriceYes);
            uint profitYes = totalPayoutYes.sub(totalSharesYes.mul(currentEvent.sharePriceYes.div(2)));
            balance -= profitYes;
            // Pay out profits to shareholders of the "yes" outcome
            uint profitPerShareYes = currentEvent.sharePriceYes.div(2);
            for (uint i = 0; i < totalSharesYes; i++) {
                address shareholder = currentEvent.shareholdersYes[i];
                payable(shareholder).transfer(profitPerShareYes);
            }
        } else {
            // Calculate total profit for the "no" outcome
            uint totalSharesNo = currentEvent.sharesNo;
            uint totalPayoutNo = totalSharesNo.mul(currentEvent.sharePriceNo);
            uint profitNo = totalPayoutNo.sub(totalSharesNo.mul(currentEvent.sharePriceNo.div(2)));
            balance -= profitNo;
            // Pay out profits to shareholders of the "no" outcome
            uint profitPerShareNo = currentEvent.sharePriceNo.div(2);
            for (uint i = 0; i < totalSharesNo; i++) {
                address shareholder = currentEvent.shareholdersNo[i];
                payable(shareholder).transfer(profitPerShareNo);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you divide by 0.

When you create an event in the createEvent function, on line 48, you set sharePriceYes to zero by doing this

```
events[_eventName] = Event(msg.sender, _eventName, eventId, _totalShares, 0, 0, _sharePriceYes, _sharePriceNo, new address[](0), new address[](0));
```

So when you call the buySharesYes() function, the line 56

```
uint shares = _payment / currentEvent.sharePriceYes;
```

basically does

```
uint shares = _payment / 0
```

which solidity doesn't like at all

I think you error comes from the createEvent() function where you assign 0 to sharePriceYes and sharePriceNo..
Check your arguments order.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works!  I should have been more aware about that.

Comment: You are welcome! If you could mark my answer as valid so other people can find it more easily, that would be great!